# Converting paragraphs with breaks to columns using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have to process the html of email messages and need to transform the html of the message into a simple table with rows and columns.

Below is one scenario in which I simply cannot find an answer:

```
<td>
    <p class="productDetails">
        Product:
        Brocade peplum pencil dress
        <br />
        Qty: 1
        <br />
        Size: Size 12
        <br />
        Colour: Black
        <br />
        Price:  GBP 50.00
        <br />
    </p>
</td>
```

I need to convert it into the following format:

```
<td>
    <td>
        Product:
        Brocade peplum pencil dress
      </td>
      <td>
        Qty: 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Size: Size 12
      </td>
      <td>
        Colour: Black
      </td>
      <td>
        Price:  GBP 50.00
       </td>
</td>
```

I will get rid of the columns within a column by using `unwrap()` but I am stuck on how to replace the `<br>` with td's because trying to use `</td><td>` to replace the `<br>` does not work.

I have a number of similar scenarios and it would be very helpful if I can get past this point.

Comment: Why will `$('br').replaceWith('</td><td>');` not work? Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hPftR/.

Comment: You can do some like this http://jsfiddle.net/aaPLv/

Comment: It seems that jQuery do not change the `<br>` to `</td><td>` but to `<td></td>`. It is doing the same in the jsfiddle example you have.

Comment: @Danko Your example seems to work and will resolve my issue but you did not post it as an answer so that I can mark it.

Comment: @jmarais now posted as answer note I don't test it onIE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to create a new table inside that `td` because you can't have nested `td` directly; you can try some like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Create the table wrapping p tag
  $('.productDetails').wrap('<table><tr>');
  //Remove p tag and wrap each item with a td
  $('.productDetails').contents().unwrap().wrap('<td>');
  //Remove td who has a br element inside
  $('td').filter(function() {
    return $(this).html() === '<br>';
    }).remove();
})
```

Check this example **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaPLv/)**

<sub>This was tested just on Chrome and Firefox</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I used the replace `<br>` with `</td><td>` idea and came up with this.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Af3wk/)**

```
var str = '<td>' + $('.productDetails').html();
str = String(str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf("<br>")) + '</td>').replace(/<br>/g, '</td><td>')

$('#table2 tr').html(str);
```

Comment: It works and could be usable but I prefer the pure jQuery solution by Danko. I can always fall back on your suggestion because I have other scenarios where getting a selector could be difficult because there is no `<p>` with a class name.

Comment: @jmarais That's okay but I could have wrote a general solution if I knew that. I just assumed this format was going to be constant.